# jQuery Bootgrid search error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I am appending data to a table from within an ajax callback.

```
// ajax
...
success: function(data) {
 $("#some-table").bootgrid("append", data.rows);
},
..
```

It works as intended except the search.

Search works for a single letter but then throws this error on an additional characters rendering it unusable.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of null
```

Its coming from this function in the lib

```
function loadData()
    {
        var that = this;

        this.element._bgBusyAria(true).trigger("load" + namespace);
        showLoading.call(this);

        function containsPhrase(row)
        {
            var column,
                searchPattern = new RegExp(that.searchPhrase, (that.options.caseSensitive) ? "g" : "gi");

            for (var i = 0; i < that.columns.length; i++)
            {
                column = that.columns[i];
                if (column.searchable && column.visible &&
                    column.converter.to(row[column.id]).search(searchPattern) > -1) // this is where it breaks
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this kind of problem, you may able to set the search properties in bootgrid.

For Example :

```
searchSettings: { delay: 250, characters: 30(just increase the character) }
```

Now you may able to search but you have enter the keyword. Its like playing with script memory. But its a easiest way to do that.